# MySQL:Why was my answer incorrect: Which film was shown in the Chaplin room most often in October 2017?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, count

I just finished taking the MySQL course as a beginner and struggled a bit with the join and sub-queries statements.

For the question, why is my answer incorrect?:

MY RESPONSE:

```
SELECT f.name, r.name, COUNT(s.room_id) AS film_times FROM films f
JOIN screenings s ON f.id = s.film_id  
JOIN rooms r ON s.room_id = r.id
WHERE r.name = 'Chaplin';
```

SOLUTION:

```
SELECT f.name, r.name, COUNT(r.name) AS film FROM films f
JOIN screenings s ON f.id = s.film_id  
JOIN rooms r ON s.room_id = r.id
WHERE r.id = 1
GROUP BY f.name
ORDER BY film DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

The most notable problem with your query is that it is missing a `GROUP BY` clause, while it has an aggregate function (`COUNT()`) in the `SELECT` clause. This is just invalid SQL.  Basically, if you want to count rows, you need to specify a grouping criteria

Also,  you are missing the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT 1`, which let you select the film with most occurences (that is, the group that contains most rows).

The `SELECT` and `FROM` clauses look fine - the solution filters rooms by `id` while you filter by `name`, but both should be OK (as long as there are no duplicate room names).

Finally, let me pinpoint that the solution is somehow flawed: not all non-aggregated columns appear in the `GROUP BY` clause, while it is a common SQL requirement (although old versions of MySQL are lax about it). Furthermore, it is grouping by film name, which (again) opens up the possibility of issues if two different films have the same name. This would better be phrased:

```
SELECT f.name, r.name, COUNT(*) AS no_occurences FROM films f
JOIN screenings s ON f.id = s.film_id  
JOIN rooms r ON s.room_id = r.id
WHERE r.id = 1
GROUP BY f.film_d, f.name, r.name
ORDER BY no_occurences DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Plus it ignores ties.